# Why do I get a syntax error in devtools::install_github?

Tags: r, devtools

I am new in working with linux. I am trying to analyse sequencing data using dropEst pipeline `https://github.com/hms-dbmi/dropEst#dropreport`. I want to run the `DropReport` and for that I need to install `dropEstR` package.

I tried by :

```
devtools::install_github('hms-dbmi/dropEst/dropestr' , dependencies = T)
```

as they suggest and I get as an error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token
>   `'hms-dbmi/dropEst/dropestr','

Do you have any idea what should I do differently?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using the "wrong" shell. You have to use R/RStudio, when you want to use the `devtools` package. From CRAN:

> Title Tools to Make Developing R Packages Easier

I just tried you command in RStudio but installation fails in the end:

```
ERROR: dependency 'Rcpp' is not available for package 'dropestr'
* removing 'C:/R/R-3.4.2/library/dropestr'
Installation failed: Command failed (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to run such script on RStudio for R. Import your project here and run it.

You can download it from [enter link description here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download)

Happy Coding.